# how to write OSClass custom query to fetch result from DB

Tags: php, osclass

I m new to OSClass(OpenSource Classifieds).

i know its similar to wordpress., but i'm not sure how to write my own query like how i do in wordpress.

The right side bar will have cities/regions as links to display advertisements from that city/region.

The City/Region name is passed through the URL, and as per requirement i need to change the URL as virtual subdomain.

For example if the user click city1, then the URL should be http://city1.domainname.com/ and results asusual.

I used htaccess to change the virtual subdomain redirection but stuck with city and region.

to determine whether its a city or region i need to do a check with the database, for that i need write a custom query to match the value with the table..

so that i can display the results regarding the city/region.

Any ideas for this problem i'm facing..

Thanks.

Comment: i too have same doubt. are you get?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look to the models inside `./oc-includes/osclass/models/` to search regions and cities and other common queries.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did in one of my plugins:

```
$conn = DBConnectionClass::newInstance();
$data = $conn->getOsclassDb();
$comm = new DBCommandClass($data);
$db_prefix = DB_TABLE_PREFIX;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `{$db_prefix}t_item` WHERE b_active=1 AND b_enabled=1";

$result = $comm->query($query);

if ($result) {
    $items = $result->result();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
       var_dump($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you save my day